# Synonym of personification that contains either the prefix andro- or morph-

Tags: synonyms, terminology

There is a specific word which contains either of the aforementioned prefixes. I read it some time ago and recall a definition somewhat similar to "giving human characteristics to something that is not human" which is why I immediately associated it with personification. Any help??

BTW, I am new to Stack Exchange, is this the correct community for this type if question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be **anthropomorphism**

> the showing or treating of animals, gods, and objects as if they are human in appearance, character, or behaviour

[Cambridge: anthropomorphism](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anthropomorphism)